# DataFixtures phpunit symfony Expected value of type got "integer" instead

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, fixtures

I am using DataFixtures and phpunit ControllerTest 
but when I using 
**phpunit tests/BankBundle/Controller/BankControllerTest.php**
I get

> Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException: Expected value of type "BankBundle\Entity\user" for association field "BankBundle\Entity\entry#$user", got "integer" instead.

I don't know how to fix it

this is my DataFixtures.php

```
<?php

namespace BankBundle\DataFixtures;

use BankBundle\Entity\entry;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

class BankFixtures implements FixtureInterface
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $bank = new entry();
        $bank->setUser(123);
        $manager->persist($bank);
        $manager->flush();
    }
}
```

entity
entry.php

```
class entry
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id",type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="user", inversedBy="id")
     */
    private $user;

    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }
    public function setUser($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

}
```

entity 
user.php

```
class user
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id",type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="balance",type="integer")
     */
    private $balance;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getBalance()
    {
        return $this->balance;
    }

    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function setBalance($balance)
    {
        $this->balance = $balance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstand how the `inversedBy` relationship works. If you inverse the relationship you need a field on the other entity that contains the related entities. These should be real entities, you do not need to concern yourself with ids as Doctrine will take care of that.

As you have a `manyToOne` relationship, the solution would be to add a property in the `user` class like:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="entry", mappedBy="user")
 */
private $entries;
```

And in your `entry` class the relationship would be:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="user", inversedBy="entries")
 */
private $user;
```

**Note** that you do not need an inversed property, so you could also simply change your `entry` class:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="user")
 */
private $user;
```

The advantage of the inversed relationship is that you can get all entries in one go from the user if add the getter:

```
$user->getEntries();
```